# NotSerializableException with Neo4j Spark Streaming Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to run a query in Neo4j using Neo4j-Spark connector. I want to pass the values from the stream (produced by Kafka as a String) into my query. However, I get serialization exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@54688d9f)
    - field (class: consumer.SparkConsumer$$anonfun$processingLogic$2, name: sc$1, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
    - object (class consumer.SparkConsumer$$anonfun$processingLogic$2, <function1>)
    - field (class: consumer.SparkConsumer$$anonfun$processingLogic$2$$anonfun$apply$3, name: $outer, type: class consumer.SparkConsumer$$anonfun$processingLogic$2)
    - object (class consumer.SparkConsumer$$anonfun$processingLogic$2$$anonfun$apply$3, <function1>)
```

Here is the code for the main function and querying logic:

```
object SparkConsumer {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val config = "neo4j_local"
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("KafkaSparkStreaming")
        setNeo4jSparkConfig(config, sparkConf)

        val sparkSession = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .config(sparkConf)
          .getOrCreate()

        val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkSession.sparkContext, Seconds(3))
        streamingContext.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
        val sqlContext = new SQLContext(streamingContext.sparkContext)
        val numStreams = 2
        val topics = Array("member_topic1")

        def kafkaParams(i: Int) = Map[String, Object](
          "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
          "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
          "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
          "group.id" -> "group2",
          "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
          "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
        )

        val lines = (1 to numStreams).map(i => KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
          streamingContext,
          LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
          ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams(i))
        ))

        val messages = streamingContext.union(lines)
        val wordsArrays = values.map(_.split(","))

        wordsArrays.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.foreach(
          data => execNeo4jSearchQuery(data)(streamingContext.sparkContext)
        ))

        streamingContext.start()
        streamingContext.awaitTermination()
      }

    def execNeo4jSearchQuery(data: Array[String])(implicit sc: SparkContext) = {
        val neo = Neo4j(sc)
        val query = "my query"

        val paramsMap = Map("lat" -> data(1).toDouble, "lon" -> data(2).toDouble, "id" -> data(0).toInt)
        val df = neo.cypher(query, paramsMap).loadDataFrame("group_name" -> "string", "event_name" -> "string", "venue_name" -> "string", "distance" -> "double")
        println("\ndf:")
        df.show()
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not allowed to access `SparkContext`, `SparkSession` or create distrbuted data structures from an executor. Therefore:

```
wordsArrays.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.foreach(
  data => execNeo4jSearchQuery(data)(streamingContext.sparkContext)
))
```

where `execNeo4jSearchQuery` calls:

```
neo.cypher(query, paramsMap).loadDataFrame
```

is not valid Spark code.

If you want to access Neo4j directly from `RDD.foreach` you have to use standard client ([AnormCypher](http://www.anormcypher.org/) seems to provide very elegant API), without conversion to Spark distributed structures.

A bit unrelated note - you [might consider using a single connection for the set of records with `foreachPartition`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd) (also [SPARK Cost of Initalizing Database Connection in map / mapPartitions context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50107222/9613318)).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Could you explain me how can I use a standard client here? I am still new to Scala

Comment: Don't mention it. I am not Neo4j expert, so I don't want suggest anything that could be a bad practice with Neo, but [AnormCypher](http://www.anormcypher.org/) has really nice getting started docs.