# spark Connect Two Database tables to produce a third data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, spark-java

**DataFrameLoadedFromLeftDatabase**=data loaded using `DataFrameReader` from first database say **LeftDB**.

I need to

- iterate through each row in this dataframe,
- connect to a second database say **RightDB**,
- find some matching record from RightDB,
- and do some business logic

This is an iterative operation so it is not simply doable with a JOIN between **LeftDB** and **RightDB** to find some new fields, create a New Dataframe **targetDF** and write into a third Database say ThirdDB using `DataframeWriter`

I know that I can use

```scala
val targetDF = DataFrameLoadedFromLeftDatabase.mapPartitions(
  partition => {
    val rightDBconnection = new DbConnection // establish a connection to RightDB 
    val result = partition.map(record => {
    readMatchingFromRightDBandDoBusinessLogicTransformationAndReturnAList(record, rightDBconnection)
  }).toList
    rightDBconnection.close()
    result.iterator
  }
).toDF()
targetDF.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "table3")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .save()
```

1. I am wondering whether apache spark is suitable for these type of chatty data processing applications
2. I am wondering whether interating throguh each record in RightDB will be too chatty in this approach
3. I am looking forward with some advices to improve this design to make use of SPARK capabilites. I also wanted to make sure the processing do not cause too much shuffle operations for performance reasons

Ref: [Related SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107222/spark-cost-of-initializing-database-connection-in-map-mappartitions-context)

Comment: Could `readMatchingFromRightDBandDoBusinessLogicTransformationAndReturnAList` be made to batch lookups in RightDB? Something like `select * from rightdb where key IN (<long list of keys collected from multiple partition records>)`.  Other than that, looks like something Spark will be fairly comfortable with.

Comment: "iterative operation" is still doable with joins and other operations. Can you elaborate more on that.

Comment: @vdep by "iterative" e.g for each recordid from leftDF i need to loop thru matching records in the rightDF and find /aggregate/consolidate some values ( can be considered similar to what we write in classical db stored procedures) which I think is not easily expressible as DF declarative apis or sql statements

Comment: The above can be easily achieved using cross joins. You might get better answers, if you can describe your exact needs.

Comment: @vdep cross join can cause performance issues right.. Please note that in my question i am loading the left data into a DF but right data is not loaded fully into a rightDF. Instead doing an iteration in the leftDF and find matchinganddoprocess direcltly from the right db

Answer (score 1):

At this kind of situations we always prefer `spark.sql`. Basically define two different DFs and join them based on a query then you can apply your business logic afterwards.

For example;

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

// Add your columns here
case class MyResult(ID: String, NAME: String)

// Create a SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("Join Tables and Add Prefix to ID Column")
  .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()

// Read the first table from DB1
val firstTable: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/DB1")
  .option("dbtable", "FIRST_TABLE")
  .option("user", "your_username")
  .option("password", "your_password")
  .load()

firstTable.createOrReplaceTempView("firstTable")

// Read the second table from DB2
val secondTable: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/DB2")
  .option("dbtable", "SECOND_TABLE")
  .option("user", "your_username")
  .option("password", "your_password")
  .load()

secondTable.createOrReplaceTempView("secondTable")

// Apply you filtering here
val result: DataFrame = spark.sql("SELECT f.*, s.* FROM firstTable as f left join secondTable as s on f.ID = s.ID")

val finalData = result.as[MyResult]
  .map{record=>
    // Do your business logic
    businessLogic(record)
  }

// Write the result to the third table in DB3
finalData.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/DB3")
  .option("dbtable", "THIRD_TABLE")
  .option("user", "your_username")
  .option("password", "your_password")
  .save()
```

If your tables are big, you can execute a query and read its results directly. If you do this you can reduce your input sizes by filtering by dates etc:

```
val myQuery = """
  (select * from table
    where // do your filetering here
  ) foo
"""

val df = sqlContext.format("jdbc").
  option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/DB").
  .option("user", "your_username")
  .option("password", "your_password")
  .option("dbtable", myQuery)
  .load()
```

Other than this, it is hard to do record specific operations  directly via spark. You have to maintain your client connections etc as custom logics. Spark designed to read/write huge amounts data. It   creates pipelines for this purpose. Simple operations will be an overhead for it. Always do your API calls (or single DB calls) in your `map` functions. If you use a cache layer in there, it could be life saving in terms of performance. Always try to use a `connection pool` in your custom database calls, otherwise spark will try to execute all of mapping operations with different connections which may create a pressure on your database and cause connection failures.

Answer (score 0):

Can think of a lot of improvements but in general all of them are going to depend on having the data pre-distributed in a HDFS, HBase, Hive database, MongoDB,...

I mean: You are thinking "relational data with distributed processing mindset" ... I though we were already beyond that XD